# git merge vs git rebase for merge conflict scenarios

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I want to make sure that I am looking at this correctly.

When I do a git merge which results into a conflict, I see the file where there is conflict as:

```
<<<<<<<<<HEAD
my local changes first
=============
The remote github changes here.
>>>>>>>>>>
```

Whereas when I run into conflicts as a result of git rebase, I see the opposite:

```
<<<<<<<<<
The remote github changes here.
=============
my local changes first
>>>>>>>>>>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622175/1256452) is right but I'd draw the diagram a bit differently.  In your own (local) Git repository, you have a series of commits like this when you start:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

That is, you have made one or more of your own commits—here, I've labeled them `I` and `J`; their real names are some big ugly hash IDs—and your branch name, `somebranch`, points to (contains the hash ID of) the last of these new commits that you made.

You then run `git pull --rebase somebranch`, or (my preferred method) the two separate commands `git fetch` followed by `git rebase origin/somebranch`.  The two-step sequence is what `git pull` does for you: it runs two Git commands, the first one always being `git fetch`, and the second one being a command you pick in advance, *before* you see what `git fetch` does.  (I like to see what `git fetch` did, and then decide: do I rebase, or merge, or wait, or do something else entirely?)

The `git fetch` step picked up new commits that someone else made, giving you this:

```
...--G--H------K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
```

Again, the uppercase letters stand in for some real actual hash ID, whatever it might be.

When you use `git merge`, Git, well, *merges*.  The graph can be drawn slightly differently to make it clearer:

```
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
```

The common starting point for the merge is commit `H`; your commit, `HEAD`, is commit `J`; and their commit is of course `L`.  So if there is a conflict, what you'll see in the in-progress merge as `HEAD` is your code from `J` and what you'll see as theirs is what's in `L`.  If you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, what you'll see as the base is what's in `H`.<sup>1</sup>

**Note that there are *three* inputs to the merge.**  Commit `H` is the *merge base*, and commits `J` and `L` (`HEAD` and theirs) are the two branch tips involved.  The final result of doing a full merge operation here will be a new *merge commit* `M`, which will point back to *both* of its two direct inputs:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
```

The *snapshot* in merge `M` is the result of applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot in commit `H`.  That is, Git found:

- the difference from `H` to `J`: what you changed;
- the difference from `H` to `L`: what they changed;

and tried to combine these on its own.  Git had a problem combining them—a *merge conflict*—and gave up and forced *you* to combine them.  Once you did, and used `git merge --continue` to finish the process, Git made `M` from the combined results.

(Commit `M` *does not* remember commit `H` directly.  Git can re-discover the merge base `H` later, if necessary, using the same process it used to find it this time.<sup>2</sup>)

---

<sup>1</sup>I like to set this option.  That way, you see not just what you put in and what they put in, but also what was there originally in the merge base commit.  This is especially useful when you or they *deleted* the code in question.

<sup>2</sup>This is actually kind of a bug, because you can run `git merge` with options that modify things, including—in some relatively rare cases—the merge base used.  The merge command should record the *options* you used, to make the merge truly repeatable.

---

When you use `git rebase`, though, Git *copies* each of your existing commits—two, in this case—one at a time.  This copying process uses a "detached HEAD", where `HEAD` points directly to a commit.  Git starts by checking out *their* commit `L` as a detached HEAD, like this:

```
...--G--H------K--L   <-- HEAD, origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   <-- somebranch
```

Now, technically, a cherry-pick is a form of merge, or as I like to put it, *merge as a verb:* the *process* of merging, without actually making a *merge commit*.  That is, you are still doing all the same work you *would* do with `git merge`.  The differences lie in the input commits to the merge, and that when you're done, the final commit *isn't* a merge commit: it's just a regular, ordinary, everyday commit, with *one* parent.

So, now that Git has done a `git checkout --detach origin/somebranch` so that *their* commit `L` is your *current* commit, it does a `git cherry-pick <hash-of-I>` to copy commit `I`.  This cherry-pick starts off the merge process.  The three inputs to this particular merge are:

- the merge base, which is the *parent* of the commit Git was told to cherry-pick: that's `H`;
- the `--ours` commit, which is always `HEAD`, and in this case is commit `L`: *their* commit; and
- the `--theirs` commit, which is the commit Git was told to cherry-pick: that's `I`, which is *your* commit.

So the `--theirs` commit for the merge operation is *your* commit, and the `HEAD` or `--ours` commit for the merge operation is *their* commit `L`!  **This is where this apparent reversal comes from.**  Git is doing a cherry-pick, which *is a form of merge*.  The `--ours` input is their commit and the `--theirs` input is your commit.

After you resolve any merge conflicts, you will run `git rebase --continue`.  (If you had run the `git cherry-pick` yourself you would run `git cherry-pick --continue`; `git rebase` takes care of doing that for you.)  This will have the cherry-pick finish up, which it does by making an *ordinary* commit:

```
                    I'  <-- HEAD
                   /
...--G--H------K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   <-- somebranch
```

The detached HEAD now points directly to this new ordinary commit, this copy `I'` of original commit `I`.  Note that commit `I'` is "just like" commit `I` except that:

- it has a different *parent* commit, `L`; and
- it has a different *snapshot*.  The snapshot in `I'` is the result of taking the difference between `H` to `I`—i.e., what you changed—and *merging* that difference with the difference between `H` and `L`.

Alas, because this is `git rebase` rather than `git merge`, we're not yet done.  Now we must copy commit `J` too, as if by `git cherry-pick <hash-of-J>`.  Our situation is still that the detached `HEAD` points to new commit `I'`.  The three inputs to *this* merge are:

- the merge base: the parent of `J`, i.e., `I`;
- the HEAD commit as `--ours`: commit `I'`, the one we just made; and
- the to-be-copied commit as `--theirs`: commit `J`, i.e., your second commit.

As always for a merge, Git compares the snapshot in the merge base to each of the two tip commits.  So Git:

1. Compares your snapshot from your `I` to your own `I'`, to see what you changed: that's *their* code you brought in via commit `L`.  That is what will show up in `<<<<<<< HEAD`, if there is a conflict.
2. Compares your snapshot from your `I` to your own `J`, to see what "they" changed: that's *your* change when you made `J`.  This is what will show up in `>>>>>>> theirs`, if there is a conflict.

This time, instead of `HEAD` being *just* their code, it's now a mix of their code *and* your code, on the `--ours` side of a conflict.  Meanwhile the `--theirs` side of any conflict continues to be their code.  Once you resolve the conflicts and use `git rebase --continue`, Git will make a new ordinary commit `J'` like this:

```
                    I'-J'  <-- HEAD
                   /
...--G--H------K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   <-- somebranch
```

Here `J'` is the cherry-picked copy of `J`.

Since these are all the commits that had to be copied, Git now finishes off the rebase by yanking the name `somebranch` away from commit `J` and attaching it instead to new commit `J'`, then re-attaching `HEAD` to the name `somebranch`:

```
                    I'-J'  <-- somebranch (HEAD)
                   /
...--G--H------K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

and the rebase is complete.  Running `git log` will show you your new copies, and no longer show you the original commits `I` and `J`.  The original commits will get reclaimed and destroyed eventually (typically some time after 30 days have passed).

**This is what makes rebasing fundamentally trickier than merging.**  A rebase involves repeated cherry-picks, and each cherry-pick *is* a merge.  If you have to copy ten commits, you are doing *ten* merges.  Git can usually do them automatically, and Git usually gets them right, but *every* merge is just Git stupidly applying some simple text-difference-combining rules, so *every* merge is an opportunity for errors.  You must carefully inspect and/or test the result.  Ideally, you should inspect and/or test all ten of these copies, but if the last one is good, probably all the others are too.

Answer (score 4):

Say your buddy and you made changes as follows using the then time as commit message.

You: 1PM, 3PM, 5PM, 7PM and so on.
Your buddy: 2PM, 4PM, 6PM, 8PM and so on.

Now see the difference between git merge and rebase, when you apply your buddy changes on your branch.

**Merge:**

```
git merge <otherLocal/remoteBranch> ## Always current branch changes takes top
```

Do (1PM, 3PM, 5PM, 7PM.. + 2PM, 4PM, 6PM, 8PM..) and show if conflicts.

**Rebase:**

```
git rebase <hisBranch> <yourBranch> ## His branch changes takes top
```

Do (2PM, 4PM, 6PM, 8PM) + (1PM) show if conflicts else keep rebasing.

Do (HEAD + 3PM) show if conflicts else keep rebasing, and so on.

```
git rebase <yourBranch> <hisBranch> ## Your branch changes takes top
```

Do (1PM, 3PM, 5PM, 7PM) + (2PM) show if conflicts else keep rebasing.

Do (HEAD + 4PM) show if conflicts else keep rebasing, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform a merge, Git views the target changes as your local source branch, and those changes appear first, on top.  On the other hand, because of the order in which a rebase happens, the branch being merged happens first, with your changed being reapplied to it.  Therefore, your work appears on the bottom in this case.  A simple diagram would help to explain what is happening during the rebase.

```
remote: -- A -- B
            \
local:       C
```

Here, you have branched off the remote and made one commit `C`, while the remote also has one new commit `B` since the branching point.  Now perform the rebase:

```
remote: -- A -- B
            \
local:       B -- C'
```

Note carefully that the step where your `C` commit gets reapplied is *after* the point when your local branch already has the `B` commit.  Therefore, from Git's point of view, your local `C` commit is the new commit coming in from the outside.