# When will git rebase have conflict?

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I have been reading several posts on this forum, progit, Youtube and some random blogs for rebase.

The most general form to conclude this subject is:

```
- A - B - C   Master
   \  D - E Topic
```

and I perform:

```
git checkout Topic
git rebase Master
```

Ideally, it would be:

```
- A - B - C - D' - E' Master, Topic
```

But the 2 concerns are:

1. Is D' = D, E' = E?
2. What is git rebase conflict?

Regarding to the first concern and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59634237/8953255),

1. Rebase do merging on D and E, and above all, with complicated input.

For example, when it goes to D, according to the post and if I am correct

1. HEAD detached to C
2. Git compares between changes from A to D and changes from A to C
3. After merging, git compares between D', D and E

And this confuses me the most. Why does merge involving more than 2 commits? Also, how does a conflict appear?

**EDIT:**

Ran some commands, please see the following:

```
git init
```

Created a Random.txt
Content: Master 1

```
git add Random.txt
git commit -m "Master 1"
```

Create new branch

```
git checkout -b rebase_conflict
```

Alter Random.txt
Content: 1

```
git add Random.txt
git commit -m "Conflict 1"
```

Alter Random. txt
Content: 2

```
git add Random.txt
git commit -m "Conflict 1"
```

Switch to master

```
git checkout master
```

Alter Random.txt
content: Master 2

```
git add Random.txt
git commit -m "Master 2"
```

Switch branch and rebase

```
git checkout rebase_conflict
git rebase master
```

Get conflict error
Alter Random.txt
Content: 1

```
git add Random.txt
git rebase --continue
```

At this point, I expect another rebase conflict, because according to the logic

```
-- Master 1 -- Master 2
  \ -- Conflict 1 -- Conflict 2
```

After first rebase

```
-- Master 1 -- Master 2 -- Conflict 1'
 \ -- Conflict 1 -- Conflict 2
```

At this stage I am expecting a new commit on top of Conflict 1'. Isn't there a merge conflict between Conflict 2 and Conflict 1'?

Because Conflict 1' Random.txt content: 1, whereas

Conflict 2 Random.txt content: 2

They change the same line, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either merging or rebasing in your above example can result in merge conflicts.  It is possible that only one or the other would have conflicts too.  To understand what rebasing does, consider the following diagram which shows what `Topic` would look like after rebasing on `Master`:

```
Topic:  -- A -- B -- C -- D' -- E'
```

Here the apostrophes indicate that the `D` and `E` commits have been reapplied onto the new base of `Master`.  As each commit is reapplied, there exists the chance for merge conflicts.  So, in the case of reapplying N commits, there could be N sets of merge conflicts.  On the other hand, a merge would always result in at most one set of merge conflicts.  If this be a concern of yours, then you might favor merging over rebasing.

Comment: Under the "each commit is reapplied" spirit, let use D as the first reapplied commit. I understand why is D being compared to C. After all, this is how rebase works, i guess. But why is the parent of D also concerned? Also, if in worst case where the 3 of them conflict on the same line of code, what would happen?

Comment: D is not being "compared" to C.  Rather, a _new_ commit is being made on top of the C commit.  Since you are making a new commit, there can be merge conflicts.   Now consider rebasing on Master with 2 new commits; now there can be 2 merge conflicts.

Comment: May I say "since I am making a new commit, there can be a merge conflict between D and C"? After resolving it, a new commit D' appears and unlike merge, D' has only 1 parent--C?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but note that `D` originally also had only one parent.

Comment: If D' is on the tip of master branch, isn't E having potential merge conflict with D'? In this case, if D' and E alter the same line of code, shouldn't there be a rebase conflict. But I didn't get one in a test run. That's weird. Is it possible to checkout the edit above?

Comment: I can't/won't change my answer based on your recent edit, which unfortunately leaves your question even harder to read than before.  If my answer is not sufficient, then I suggest either reading a good tutorial or maybe asking another question later on.